# Delphi array constructor alternative

Tags: delphi

So I have this method that I should call, and it takes an array constructor as an argument, as shown here:

```
myTTable.InsertRecord([var1, var2, var3]);
```

The problem is that I have a very big number of variables that I managed to put into an array of strings `params`. But I seem unable to pass it as an argument.

All these do not work :

```
myTTable.InsertRecord(params);
myTTable.InsertRecord([params]);
myTTable.InsertRecord(Slice(params, 88)); // I know I have 88 elements
```

The only way I found is to write :

```
myTTable.InsertRecord([params[0], params[1], params[2], ... params[87]]);
```

Which I prefer not to do. Is there another way?

Also, I'm using a pretty old version of Delphi and I cannot upgrade for some corporate reasons.

Comment: Please show the signature of `InsertRecord` and the type of `params`

Comment: @StefanGlienke: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.InsertRecord

Comment: Thanks @Uwe for notifying me on my mistake. I thought `myTTable` was OP's own invention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`InsertRecord()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.InsertRecord) takes a [Variant Open Array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)) (`array of const`) as input. The *typical* way to construct such an array in Delphi is using the bracket syntax around every individual value, as you already discovered.

However, an `array of const` is really an `array of TVarRec`, which you can build up manually (with caution! As [`TVarRec`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TVarRec) has gotchas in how certain types, like strings, have to be passed in it).

For example:

```pascal
procedure DoInsert(params: array of string);
var
  v: array of TVarRec;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(v, Length(params));
  for i := 0 to Length(params)-1 do
  begin
    {$IF CompilerVersion >= 20}
    // Delphi 2009 and later...
    v[i].VType := vtUnicodeString;
    v[i].VUnicodeString := Pointer(params[i]);
    {$ELSE}
    // Delphi 2007 and earlier...
    v[i].VType := vtAnsiString;
    v[i].VAnsiString := Pointer(params[i]);
    {$IFEND}
  end;
  myTTable.InsertRecord(v);
end;

var
  params: array of String;
begin
  SetLength(params, 88);
  // populate params as needed...
  DoInsert(params);
end;
```

Comment: I have a hard time compiling this, i've just checked and it turned out to be Delphi 2.
it says "incompatible types string and array" on using SetLength, same thing if I change Length(params) to 88.
I think it doesn't even recognize that $IF

Comment: @FiRas what problem are you having exactly? You need to be more specific. Is it the `{$IF}` statements? `{$IF}` and `CompilerVersion` were introduced in Delphi 6. Just remove those statements and use the `vtAnsiString` block for Delphi 2 (`AnsiString` was introduced in Delphi 2, `UnicodeString` in Delphi 2009).

Comment: @FiRas dynamic arrays are introduced in Delphi 4. So for Delphi 2, you will have to allocate the arrays manually. Does Delphi 2 have `GetMem()` or `AllocMem()` available? However you manage to allocate the string array, you will have to do the same thing for the `TVarRec` array